# Aligning h:outputText inside a p:datatable

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have an `<h:outputText value="#{xx.nameame}" />` which is given below

```
<p:dataTable>
  <p:column width="200"  >
    <f:facet name="header"    >
      <h:outputText value="Header1" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{xx.addFlag == false}">
      <h:outputText value="#{xx.nameame}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I want to align the values coming for this field `<h:outputText value="#{xx.nameame}" />` in left side of the cell example : `text-align:left`

But the problem is that JSF itself, considering the column as div tag, is assigning the the css by default which is:

```
.ui-dt-c {
     white-space: normal;
     text-align: center;
}
```

Due to the above, the text is aligned center. If I change the above to `text-align: to left`, all the datatable will get changed in other screens too.
Hence  I want to apply the change only to the above datatable and not for the others.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What is the rendered html for this?

Comment: 'JSF' is not considering the column as a div, it is PrimeFaces **in older versions** that rendered a div around the content. The column cell is still a `<td>`. So highly upvoted answer is not relevant anymore in recent PF versions and you can 'just' add a style(class) on the column. And in this case a more specific selector would have helped too to apply it to just one datatable... All basic css

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For older PrimeFaces versions (pre 5.2), use this code to make it left align as.

```
<div align="left"><h:outputText value="#{xx.nameame}" /></div>
```

For newer PrimeFaces versions, see [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180982/aligning-houtputtext-inside-a-datatable#answer-39804833) where you can just put the style on the column

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me!
I'm using <p:outputPanel> instead of the <div>. It also works.

Comment: This answer was not good (although it works). A more specific selector would have worked too to apply it to one datatable

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `style` property with `float` option like;

```
<h:outputLabel value="Max" style="float:left" />
```

Comment: Yes, but e.g. `style="text-align:center"` does not work since the outputLabel renders a span, not a div. Putting `tyle="text-align: left"`  on the column would be better

Answer (score 2):

In modern PrimeFaces versions (> 5.1) the div around the content is not rendered anymore, so the problem was solved in a different way (Because when you use Qadir Hussain answer, if the web page is in mobile view column value is shown below of the column name(expected at the opposite of the column name)).

The div around the content of the column 'content' is not present anymore in recent PrimeFaces versions so the following 'just works'

```
<p:column style="text-align: left" class="TexLeft">
......
....
</p:column>
```

So you can give a style or a class or both to  element, that will solves your responsive or more complicated issues.